# Outlook VBA script will not run

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I created a VBA script in Outlook 2010 but the only way it will run is by clicking on the play button while in Outlook VBA as indicated in the image below:

[image: VBA]

Why won't it run when I select the VBA script from the menu as indicated in the image below? I have already signed the VBA script by using "SelfCert.exe".

[image: macro menu]

The other two VBA scripts in the list do run when they are selected from the menu. Below is the code of the VBA script that does not run:

```
Sub ReplaceIPs()
    Dim Insp As Inspector
    Dim obj As Object

    Set Insp = Application.ActiveInspector
    Set obj = Insp.CurrentItem

    obj.HTMLBody = Replace(obj.HTMLBody, "192.168.1", "255.255.255")

    Set obj = Nothing
    Set Insp = Nothing
End Sub
```

The above VBA script is supposed to find and replace all instances of "192.168.1" with "255.255.255" in the body of the email that is being composed.

Comment: What happens if you put 192.168.1 into the body of your message and then run your macro? I tried your code here and it did work. This will not replace IP addresses in the header of an email

Comment: I do add 192.168.1 in the body. That's how I test it but it does not work. Did you add the code as a module in VBA?

Comment: Yes I did. See my answer and see if that resolves your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Module name can't contain a Macro of the same name. Rename  the **module** `ReplaceIPs` to something else or rename the **macro**/subroutine `ReplaceIPs` with something else. If they are both the same it won't resolve properly

Comment: Thanks! That's what the problem was. I was sure that I tried it with a different name but I guess I did not.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone, none of the methods in my Outlook VBA module were getting control, because the entire module was failing to pre-compile, because I had an extra "." in front of a "Sub" stmt

Trying to run an arbitrary method ("F8") showed the problem.